# "$ ./propellor --list-fields" yields "propellor: Prelude.read: no parse"

Tags: haskell, deployment

I am trying to specify a private field using Haskell's [Propellor](https://propellor.branchable.com/) deployment library.

As context: the field in question is a file whose content I want to encrypt and have propellor place on the destination server during deployment. However, I haven't gotten nearly that far; before even attempting to set the field, I have run into an error while attempting to simply view propellor's current private fields.

Specifically, when I run the command to view fields, `$ ./propellor --list-fields`, it asks for my gpg key, prints some gpg key information, and then the following:

```
Currently set data:
Field                                     Context                     Used by
-----                                     -------                     -------
propellor: Prelude.read: no parse
```

There should be some fields present which were set previously, but somehow they are not displayed here and instead I get only the `propellor: Prelude.read: no parse` error message. I have not yet attempted to add my own field.

It seems that propellor is having an issue trying to parse something, but I do not know what that could be. I realize this is not a lot to go on but am not sure what else to do. Has anyone run into a similar error with Haskell's propellor before or know what the issue could be?

Comment: Please show us a bit more info on your config/setup right now it seems blackbox debugging on a roughly sketched problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this question was so vague, but there was very little to go on from the error message. The issue is now resolved and here is an explanation in case it is helpful to anyone who comes across it while facing a similar error.

The code contained an instance of a configuration data type defined not in a module, but in a text file being read in via the Read class. In short, the issue was that I had altered the data type without comprehensively updating the text-defined configuration instance to accomodate the type change.

In the long-form version of the explanation the issue is sneakier, involving merging the data type change over a change to the text-configuration which was not recognized as in conflict due to no line conflicts.

But essentially the error was failure to read in a data type instance defined in text-form.

I have plans to define the configuration data instance in a module rather than reading it in from text, which should be caught by the compiler and give a more meaningful error message should a similar error arise.

Answer (score 1):

Your self-answer is correct; here I will just look at the issue in a different light.

The error you got points to the [`read` function in `Prelude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read). `read` is an example of a *partial function*: its type...

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

... says that it can convert `String`s into a value of any type `a` with a `Read` instance; however, we known that this does not work for all `String`s, as the parsing might fail. To put it more dramatically, the type of `read` *is a lie*.

It is generally a good idea to avoid partial functions, not only because more often than not they are bugs waiting to happen (e.g. you assume the parse will never fail due to some precondition in your business logic, and then the precondition changes), but also because they tend to give extremely uninformative error messages (as you just noticed). In the case of `read`, for instance, a nicer alternative is [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe), which returns `Nothing` if the parsing fails. That gives an opportunity to react to the failure. In dfferent situations you might, for instance, find it appropriate to ask the user to retry, supply a default value or, if there is no other recourse, terminate the program with an error message that explains what went wrong in terms of what you are trying to do.